# Highcharts changing tooltip datetime with formatter

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, momentjs

I have a graph that looks like the below. By default each tooltip value is in it's own tooltip "bubble", with the datetime at the bottom of the Y axis (hovering on top of the X labels).

[image: default tooltip]

The problem is that changing the format of the datetime to match locale is not dynamic with Highcharts. I know I could have users change the `dateTimeLabelFormats` to match their locale, but I'm looking to leverage moment.js and their locale formatting built in.

I only need to change the datetime in these charts and nothing else.

When I try this code below, it gives me the locale leverage I'm looking for, but the tooltips are merged into 1 box and doesn't have that same feel as default.

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        //minute: '%e %b %H:%M',
        hour: '%e %b %H:%M'
    },
    // For locale control with moment. Combined momentjs with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33939715/1177153
    formatter: function() {
        var toolTipTxt = '<b>'+ moment.unix(this.x / 1000).format("LLL") +'</b>';  
          $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            toolTipTxt += '<br/><span style="color:'+ point.series.color +'">  ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y+'</span>';
        });
        return toolTipTxt;
    },
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true
},
```

[image: moment.js locale formatting]

Is there a way to emulate default tooltip with the formatter? Individual "bubbles" for the values and the timestamp hovering at the bottom?

Is it possible to use `xDateFormat` with moment.js somehow?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that works, right from the [Highcharts API documentation for tooltip split](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.split).

The [jsfiddle example from the API documentation](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-split/) had everything I needed (except moment.js).

I must have overlooked this 100 times today. Here's the final code that worked for me, and a screenshot of the result.

Now the tooltip's header will be in the right locale without the user changing any code.

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    // For locale control with moment.js - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.split
    formatter: function () {
        // The first returned item is the header, subsequent items are the points
        return [moment.unix( this.x / 1000).format("LLL")].concat(
            this.points.map(function (point) {
                return "<span style='color:" + point.series.color + "'>\u25CF</span> " + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
            })
        );
    },
    split: true,
},
```

[image]